# Liquibase database refactoring

Tags: mysql, refactoring, liquibase

I'm in need of a tool that can generate code for refactoring MySQL databases, and the tool [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) has caught my attention.

However, I can't tell from studying [the online documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/rename_column.html) whether "refactoring", for the example of a data column rename operation

1. merely changes the column name, or
2. whether any references to this column are changed as well in other entities such as views, procedures, and triggers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liquibase does not find and replace references to the renamed column, it simply renames the column.

It relies on you to find and know what references and dependencies need to be changed.